# Killing a program with SIGINT is rendering my shell unusable, why?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I'm working on bash in Ubuntu and I have a python program using some threading code. It works well, but after I kill it pressing CTRL+C, the shell just breaks. No input is shown to me (although it still is interpreted in the background) and the only thing that works is the enter key, albeit in a weird fashion.

```
thunder@machine:~/server/api$ thunder@machine:~/server/api$
```

Well actually it doesn't work, it just places a new prompt line right next to the previous one.

I think something is messing up with my shell, so I was wondering is there a way to "reset" it? right now I have to open a new shell session and that is very annoying.

To know what is causing this problem to begin with would be great, but I don't think that's possible with the little information I just provided here. And frankly I have no idea of where in my code I could be messing things up, since like I said before the program does work correctly.

Nelson

Comment: In your terminal type `reset` and then press `ctrl+J`

Comment: A possible explanation is that your program corrupted the *tty*; read [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the terminal by typing

`reset`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

into the bash shell (you might need to do it blind, i.e. without seeing the characters being echoed).

See [`man 1 reset`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/reset).

Comment: You might also need to press Ctl-j instead of Enter.